# R Time difference between 2 columns in milliseconds

Tags: r, datetime

I have a dataset containing performance data. Column 1 contains the END_DATE and column 2 the START_DATE.
The format of the datetime in both columns: 03-08-16 08:55:59,177000000
I want to add a new column where the time difference in milliseconds is stored.

Example:

> column 1: 03-08-16 08:55:59,177000000
>
> column 2: 03-08-16 08:55:59,888000000
>
> new column in seconds: 0,711

I tried to convert to as.POSIX.. but somehow the milliseconds gets lost. There was an answer stating that the "OS" format option would do the trick but i wasn't succesfull:

> time = as.POSIXct("03-08-16 08:56:06,345000000", format="%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%OS")
>
> time
>
> [1] "2016-08-03 08:56:06 CEST"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you will need to use `sub` to convert your Yuropean decimal (comma) to a decimal "point" (period).

Answer (score 1):

Expansion of my comment:

```
d <- data.frame(col1= '03-08-16 08:55:59,177000000', col2= '03-08-16 08:55:59,888000000')

d2 <- data.frame( lapply(d, sub, patt="[,]", repl="."))
d2
#-------
                         col1                        col2
1 03-08-16 08:55:59.177000000 03-08-16 08:55:59.888000000
#-------
 d3 <- data.frame( lapply(d2, as.POSIXct, format= "%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%OS")  )
 d3
#--------
                 col1                col2
1 2016-08-03 08:55:59 2016-08-03 08:55:59
#-------
 difftime(d3$col1, d3$col2)
#-------
Time difference of -0.711 secs
```

Comment: Set `options(digits.secs = 3)` to see the fractional seconds when the POSIXct objects are printed.