# Using xts or zoo to find faster and accurate Time differences in R

Tags: r, time, xts, zoo

I'm looking to find faster and more accurate methods to find the difference between two times, preferably using the `xts` or `zoo` packages. At the moment I would like to find the number of milliseconds difference between two times, and to do this I have been using the `difftimes` function (with units set to seconds and I then multiply this number by 1000 to get milliseconds - for example: `as.numeric(difftime(time2, time1, units = "secs")) * 1000`).

This seems to work reasonably well, but I'm hoping for something faster and more accurate so I wish to use `xts` or `zoo` instead. However, I'm not sure how to go about finding the difference between two times using these packages.

Are they any particular functions in `xts` or `zoo` which can find the difference between two times? In addition, are they any functions which can allow me to compute the millisecond difference between two times?

EDIT: There's something important I forgot to include in my original topic: the reason why I want more accurate time methods is due to a rounding issue in my times. I am having a similar issue as given in this topic here: [How R formats POSIXct with fractional seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726034/how-r-formats-posixct-with-fractional-seconds) where my times are off by a fraction of a second (e.g. I get the time `11:12:53.332` rather than the time `11:12:53.333`). Up until now I have 'fixed' this issue by including adding a smaller fraction of time to the number i.e. I can change  `11:12:53.332` to `11:12:53.333` by writing `11:12:53.332 + 1e-6`. However, I now need to go down to microseconds, so rather than 'fix' this issue by adding another fraction I would much rather use a package or function or something to achieve this task.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39131578/r-time-difference-between-2-columns-in-milliseconds

Answer (score 1):

I don think you need any of these packages. Run the following code:

```
a = Sys.time()
Sys.sleep(0.0001)
b = Sys.time()
difftime(b,a)
```

Now run the code again, but first run:

```
options(digits=20)
```

The object is stored with high accuracy, but just printed with a limited number of digits. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response! Will including more significant figures bypass the 'rounding' issue that R has? I have a similar problem as given in this topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726034/how-r-formats-posixct-with-fractional-seconds where I currently have 3 significant figures and I find that some times are slightly different (for instance, I have the time 11:12:53.332 rather than 11:12:53:333)